# Conditional import from multiple spreadsheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

There have 3 spreadsheets:

1. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-nezOLfFas0TRFo-7PkP1Xk_DErlnv0sz3ysm8hdPpI/edit?usp=sharing
2. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eZTDfjVryebvyTsELyNQCBDwoZcTsBvQYV-CdXXO2x4/edit?usp=sharing
3. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ItIjjQpwR_shcQxoNn96pxPEPxpawLkl6o3n1x28iWs/edit?usp=sharing

> -> I want to import data from 1. to 2 where 1(communication!A:C) ColB=Member 1, ColC=ToContact/Contacted/ContactedUs/ContactAgain
>
> ---
>
> -> Improt Data from 1 to 3 where 1(communication!A:C) ColB=Member 2, ColC=ToContact/Contacted/ContactedUs/ContactAgain

Help Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> import data from 1. to 2 where 1(communication!A:C) ColB=Member 1, ColC=ToContact/Contacted/ContactedUs/ContactAgain

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1-nezOLfFas0TRFo-7PkP1Xk_DErlnv0sz3ysm8hdPpI", "Communication!A:C"), 
 "where Col2 = 'Member 1' 
    and lower(Col3) matches 'tocontact|contactagain|contactedus'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

> Improt Data from 1 to 3 where 1(communication!A:C) ColB=Member 2, ColC=ToContact/Contacted/ContactedUs/ContactAgain

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1-nezOLfFas0TRFo-7PkP1Xk_DErlnv0sz3ysm8hdPpI", "Communication!A:C"), 
 "where Col2 = 'Member 2' 
    and lower(Col3) matches 'tocontact|contactagain|contactedus'", 0)
```

[image: 0]